# invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript in a vector of list <pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++, list, vector

I had a class with private properties:

```
class Ranking {
private:
    struct empar {
        int id_org;
        list <pair <int,int> > l_repr;
    };

    vector <empar> rank;
};
```

Now, I have changed this class because the integer id_org doesn't use. Then

Declaration private atributes class:

```
class Ranking { 
private:    
list <pair <int,int> > l_repr;  
vector <l_repr> rank;

//.............
};
```

I could access to strut with this code:

```
void Ranking::sort_ranking(int id_1, int id_2, int id_3)
      list <pair <int,int> >:: iterator it = rank[id_1].l_repr.end();
          pair<int,int> rep;
      rep.first = id_1+1;
      rep.second = id_3;
      rank[id_pad].l_repr.insert(it, rep);
      //............
}
```

But, now how I changed the compiler crash.

When I want to access a list througt a index I use this code:

```
void Ranking::sort_ranking(int id_1, int id_2, int id_3)
{
list <pair <int, int> > l1= rank[id_1];
list <pair <int,int> >:: iterator it = l1.end();

// ...
}
```

The compiler send me this message and I don't know that means
`

> Ranking.cpp: In member function ‘void Ranking::sort_ranking(int)’:
>   Ranking.cpp:52:21: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
>   Ranking.cpp:52:47: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
>   Ranking.cpp:55:26: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
>   Ranking.cpp:55:53: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
>   Ranking.cpp:56:22: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
>   Ranking.cpp:56:49: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

- Do you want if is possible create a `vector` of `list <pair <int,int> >` ?
- How can I access a `list` from a `vector`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question would benefit from a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please create one so we can better help you. You might even find the answer yourself while creating it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I reedit the post. Sorry

Comment: Which line is line 56?

Comment: @sepp2k the error was here: list <pair <int,int> >:: iterator it = rank[id_1].l_repr.end(); when I tryed to catch the value. thanks for the interest!

Comment: Those error messages don't correspond to any of the code you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For containers templates you need a data type.

So use `typedef` keyword for `l_repr` :

```
typedef   list <pair <int,int> > l_repr; 
// ^^^ 
vector <l_repr> rank;
```

There could be other error(s) too.

Comment: Thanks POW, this is a great solution! I know that It's a stupid error but I have wasted a lot of time thinking where was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a vector of list of pair int, int

```
std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> v;
```

But I'm not sure what you would use that for, since it's quite messy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I declare a namespace in the program header ;)